# how to tell if specifications are modelled using database oriented approach or class design oriented approach

Tags: database, oop, database-design, class-design

Given a problem specification, how to tell if it is a database design problem or class design(object oriented design) problem?

Answer (score 2):

What comes to my mind, is that in OOP, classes(objects) contain methods, whereas a database is just a collection of relationships and values.
Therefore:

If you can say a problem is about how "things" in the specification relate to each other you have a database design problem.

If it is about what the "things" in the specification can do, you're going to be modeling more along object oriented programming.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a database and creating domain objects, it's both. Database design and class design are two different things, and both are necessary if you're using a database and classes. It's not like you choose one or the other.

This is where an ORM comes into play. When your data layer retrieves information from the database, a typical approach is to transform the relational data into your domain object(s) and pass that to the business logic layer so the rest of your application can deal with domain objects instead of a relational model.

Then your ORM does the opposite when persisting data: it takes a domain entity and turns it back into a relational structure that can be saved to the database.

Note: I'm assuming a relational database here. If not, substitute relational for whatever type of persistence layer you're using.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the only specifications which should be addressed as database-oriented problems are those which are focused on the manipulation of structured data types. If your specification is all about "store a customer record", "delete an order record", "change the value of price from 12 to 33 for record matching specifcation", you've got a database project.

I haven't seen that kind of problem specification since the Cobol team I worked in employed a systems ~~anarchist~~ analyst. Almost every project I've worked on since has had requirements that were not about how data was stored, but what the data meant.

If you get a requirement that says "Users may create Customers. Customers can place orders. Orders contain products. Orders can have delivery methods, payment methods, and status. Status follows a business process", you have an OO problem. You probably need a storage mechanism - and a database would be an excellent choice - but you have business logic that cannot be exclusively implemented by creating structured data types and relationships.